# PHP Laravel how to check if checkbox is checked in controller

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm building a `laravel`-app where I'm connecting `mailchimp` to the contact-form. The user has to accept conditions and has the possibility to receive the newsletter by checking a checkbox. Right now, when the user accepts both the conditions and the newsletter, the form is submitted successfully, but when the user does not check the newsletter checkbox, the form is not submitted and I don't really know why.

here the input

```
<input name="conditions" value="1" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="applyConditions" required>
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" class="custom-control-input" id="contactNewsletterSubscribe">
```

and my controller:

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
public function store()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), [
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'name' => ['required', 'string'],
        'phone' => ['string'],
        'subject' => ['required', 'string'],
        'message' => ['required', 'string'],
        'conditions' => ['accepted', 'boolean'],
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()
            ->json($validator->messages(), 400);
    }

    if (request()->has('newsletter')) {
        Newsletter::subscribePending(request()->email);

        if (!Newsletter::lastActionSucceeded()) {
            return response()
                ->json($validator->messages(), 400);
        }
    }

    Mail::to('my@mail.com')
        ->send(new ContactUsMessage([
            'email' => request()->email,
            'name' => request()->name,
            'phone' => request()->phone,
            'subject' => request()->subject,
            'message' => request()->message,
        ]));

    return response()->json('OK', 200);
}
```

}

When I check both `conditions` and the `newsletter` checkboxes, the form data returns:

```
conditions: 1
newsletter: on
```

When conditions are accepted but the newsletter checkbox is unchecked, the form data returns:

```
conditions: 1
newsletter: undefined
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT**

I'm sending the form data with jquery/axios:

```
if ($('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked')) {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked').val()
   );
} else {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]').val()
    );
}
```

Comment: How do you send your form? jQuery?

Comment: @Tarasovych yes I am... please check my updated question...

Comment: What if you remove if/else, and just append `val()` every time?

Comment: you can add value in checkbox

Comment: By the way, *"the form is not submitted"* - any errors in console?

Comment: Please use proper tagging - if you submit your form using Javascript or jQuery, this is in no way related to PHP nor Laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

First of all, your jQuery code is not much of use:

```
if ($('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked')) {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked').val()
   );
} else {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]').val()
    );
}
```

In both cases you are trying to get `value` attribute which is not exists. and you get `on` only because it's a browser default behavior to assign `On` value to checked checkbox when `<input>` tag is not have `value` attribute.

Moreover, if you set the attribute you will get its value all the time, regardless of `checked` status of checkbox ;). Try it to see for yourself.

Next, I would go with a simple code, like this:

```
formData.append(
    "newsletter",
    $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked').length
);
```

w/o any conditions. in the controller you will get either `1`, either `0`.

then, in the controller, you could do like this:

```php
if (!empty(request()->newsletter)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for and it makes total sense! Thanks alot :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
if ($('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked')) {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       $('#contact input[name="newsletter"]:checked').val()
   );
} else {
    formData.append(
       "newsletter",
       "off"
    );
}
```

So it should be `newsletter: off` on the server.

P. S. I'd suggest to use boolean values for checkboxes.